# .NET Core POSIX IPC

Tags: .net-core, posix, ipc

Does .NET Core have support for POSIX IPC? 
I want to use Message Queues and Shared Memory. 
MemoryMappedFile does not seem to work on Linux.
Is PInvoke my only chance?

Any help is appreciated 
Thanks

Comment: JIC, there's no PInvoke for POSIX, but you can try
Mono.Posix.NETStandard

Comment: @MaximSaplin - Could you please provide more information (or a link) about why there is no P/Invoke for POSIX?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/native-interop/pinvoke - take a look at official docs, same old function mappings with DllImport can be used with POSIX APIs but pointging to .so libs on Linux rather than to .DLL on Windows. Mono.Posix.NETStandard saves the time since it has many mappings created for you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.NET Core `System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles` are supported on unixes. There are some limitations though. For details see implementation of [MemoryMappedFile.Unix.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles/src/System/IO/MemoryMappedFiles/MemoryMappedFile.Unix.cs) in `dotnet/corefx` repo.

Message Queues are unsupported yet.

Comment: thanks, I get a PlatformNotSupportedException in var mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateNew("/tmp/sharedfile", 10000) for some reason...not sure which limitation applies here

Comment: What is your .NET Core version?

Comment: It is .NET Core 2.0

Comment: You are hitting lack of support for named MemoryMappedFiles see: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/8ef2b325790135e86bc6aac2cdb6eaf7ff37e17f/src/System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles/src/System/IO/MemoryMappedFiles/MemoryMappedFile.Unix.cs#L34

Comment: u are correct thanks. Here is the issue on GitHub https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/20091 and here is an example https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles/tests/MemoryMappedFile.CrossProcess.cs#L13